# Redirect http to https via nginx

Tags: nginx, https

I have a completely stock installation of nginx version: nginx/1.10.0 (Ubuntu) on Ubuntu 16.04 other than /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default being replaced with the following...

```
server {
    listen 443 default_server;
    server_name www.example.com;

    ssl_certificate           /etc/nginx/cert.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key       /etc/nginx/cert.key;

    ssl on;
    ssl_session_cache  builtin:1000  shared:SSL:10m;
    ssl_protocols  TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_ciphers HIGH:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!CAMELLIA:!DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; # my existing apache instance
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # re-write redirects to http as to https, example: /home
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
    }
}
```

Which has the purpose of being a https wrapper around a http api running on port 8080.

I am now trying to make it so that when someone goes to my site on http port 80, it redirects them to https. I have tried every other documented fix, mostly based around something like this...

```
server {
   listen 80;
   return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```

... and nothing seems to have any effect what so ever and you always get the WELCOME TO NGINX page.

Comment: Did you try like this ? https://bjornjohansen.no/redirect-to-https-with-nginx

Comment: yes, attempted and failed. still get http "Welcome to nginx!" page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out my work has an insanely aggressive caching proxy and no matter what I did just returned the default nginx page.

fixed with..

```
    // ...
    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:8080; # my existing apache instance
        proxy_set_header Host $host;

        # re-write redirects to http as to https, example: /home
        proxy_redirect http:// https://;
        add_header Cache-Control "no-cache";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/67316/in-nginx-how-can-i-rewrite-all-http-requests-to-https-while-maintaining-sub-dom) question,

You are missing the `server_name` parameter in your config.

```
server {
       listen         80;
       server_name    my.domain.com;
       return         301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
}
```

Comment: attempted and failed.

Comment: did you change the server name to `localhost` if you are running this in your machine?

Comment: yes I did. zero change. its as if the port 80 server config is being overridden by something elsewhere.

Comment: Did you restart the server once the config was changed?

Comment: yes, and rebooted the machine completely to be 100% sure

Answer (score 0):

I want to leave a more recent update here since nginx has changed since this question was asked.

You can redirect http requests with the following lines:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name example.com;
    rewrite     ^   https://example.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```